# JIRA filter board by epic status = "in progress"

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

We are trying to create a Kanban Board which only displays stories and tasks which either belong to no epic, or who's epic is "in progress".

We found the docs for adding a [board sub-filter](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-filters#ConfiguringFilters-AddingaSub-FilterforKanbanboards) and using [JQL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/advanced-searching-861257209.html) to do so. However we haven't found the right query combination. Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This JQL querry filters the issues of type "Story" and "Task" that have either no epic linked to them or that have an epic linked and the epic's status is at "in progress". Is this what you are looking for JQL wise?

```
issuetype in (Story,Task) AND "Epic Link" IS (EMPTY) OR ("Epic Link" IS NOT (EMPTY) AND "Epic Status" IS (in progress))
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could benefit from more detail. Please edit it to explain *how/why* your solution addresses the OPs question.

Comment: This does not seem to work for custom epic statuses.  Has the syntax or approach changed?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is arguably more suited to a saved query rather than a board. Have you considered using a dashboard to show a filter result? You could have separate *Filter result gadgets* for:

1. Stories & tasks with no epic link
2. Epics in progress

@Berchy's JQL works well and can be adapted for both of these filters.

Answer (score 0):

Came across very similar task - displaying all tasks that are linked to Epics in progress. What I did - I selected all ISSUES that are not Done, and then displayed them on the Kanban board and set up swimlanes "By epics". Only this way you don't see DONE issues from active Epics as well.